# Exchange contact with two numbers not working

Tags: contacts, exchange

I've got contact with two phone numbers stored as mobile phone and mobile phone 2. But contact page has only one SMS button and I'm only able to text one of them (no way to tell which).

My google searches suggests, that there should be button in app bar for changing numbers, but it's not shown. Also in a contact details, I see only one of those numbers. When I choose to edit the contact, I see both numbers simultaneously.

How can I text or call both of these numbers?

Nokia Lumia 1520, WP 8 Black update, contact synced with Exchange server.

Answer (score 1):

Tap on SMS button will show messaging window and you can see [image] at bottom. Tap the right most icon with double arrows and you can switch between numbers or facebook here.

Comment: This button is not showing up, even though the contact has multiple numbers, I only have first two.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the message (texting) app, if there are multiple numbers, the right most icon will have two horizontal arrows pointing in different directions. When you tap it, you can select the other number.